# How to get `EventData` in `onEvent()` in `Photon Server`

Tags: android, hashmap, photon

I am working on `multiplayer` game using `Photon Server`. I am send sending some data using `HashMaps` through `loadBalancingPeer.opRaiseEvent` but i am not able to get data in `onEvent` function of `LoadBalancingClient`.

Here is my custom event code.

```
public void sendSomeEvent(int playerPosition) {

        HashMap<Object, Object> eventContent = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        eventContent.put("key1", "ABC");

        this.loadBalancingPeer.opRaiseEvent((byte) 1, eventContent, false,
                (byte) 0); // this is received by OnEvent()
    }
```

Here is `onEvent()` code.

```
@Override
public void onEvent(EventData eventData) {
    super.onEvent(eventData);

    switch (eventData.Code) {
    case (byte) 1:
        String value = (String) eventData.Parameters
                .get("key1");
        ApplicationManager.onEventReceived(ab);
        break;      
    }
    // update the form / gui
    ApplicationManager.onClientUpdateCallback();
}
```

In this function i am getting `null` value, but it shows patameter data in this form `{-11={key1=ABC}, -2=1}`. 
Please help me where i am getting wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you using value variable

Comment: Where you are adding `-11` in Map?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i am also confused why it is showing values in this format, i am not sending `-11` or  `-2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used Photon but after looking at API docs, I think you are doing things wrong. EventData is also kind of a Map.

In case of raised event the value of `eventData.Code` should actually be `OpertationCode.RaiseEvent` and your event `( byte ) 1` will be mapped with key `EventCode.Code` in the map.

In this EventData, event code is mapped with key `EventCode.Code` and your data is mapped with key `ParameterCode.Data`.

So... to get your sent hashmap out of `EventData` you need to do a `eventData.get( ParameterCode.Code )`.

I think following should work fine. Try it, and give me a detailed error log, if this does not work.

```
switch ( eventData.Code ) {
    // If it is a RaiseEvent
    case OperationCode.RaiseEvent:
        switch ( eventData.get( EventCode.Code ) ) {
            // If it is your event.
            case (byte) 1:
                HashMap< Object, Object > map = (HashMap<Object, Object>) eventData.get( ParameterCode.Data );

                HashMap< String, String > smap = new HashMap< String, String >();
                for( Object key : map.keySet() ) {
                    smap.put( (String) key, ( String ) map.get( key ) );
                }
                // Now smap is the HashMap<String, String> that you sent.
                // do something
                break;
        }
        break;
}
```

Note :: Now I am pretty confident that it should work.